# Selenium Python not locating element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have a Selenium python code that I am running on an internal Dynamic CRM website to download data.
For the most part the code works until the last step where it does not locate the element "Export Data". Export Data comes up in a new ribbon on the toolbar triggered by our previous step. Below is the code and HTML.
Also attached the HTML portion of the Export. What am I doing wrong?
Please help and let me know if you need more information

Screen 1 CRM shows the Results button when clicked takes us to Screen 2 that is a new tab on the toolbar:
[image: related image]
Screen 2 with the new tab on toolbar
[image: related image]
HTML code of Export
[image: related image]

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import os
from pathlib import Path
import shutil


#--| Chrome Setup
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
prefs={"download.default_directory":r"


#Setup Chrome preferences
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

#Direct Link to NGL Five year Forecast Data Only
browser.get('<URL>')
browser.maximize_window()

# Store current window position
window_before = browser.window_handles[0]

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)

#Key in Email
web_loginscreen = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'i0116')))  
web_loginscreen.send_keys("<UserName>")

# Next Button
web_loginbutton = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]')
web_loginbutton.click()

window_before_title = browser.title
print(window_before_title)
#Filter button 
web_filter = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="advancedFindLauncher"]/button/span/span')))  
web_filter.click()

#browse to newly opened download window
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])
window_after = browser.window_handles[1]
window_after_title = browser.title
print(window_after_title)


# Select Agreements
time.sleep(5)

# locate all elements
 
frame = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contentIFrame0"]')
browser.switch_to.frame(frame)
# 

dropdown = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="slctPrimaryEntity"]')
dropdown.click()

agreements = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="slctPrimaryEntity"]/option[35]')
agreements.click()
# print(dropdown.text)

# Go back out of iframe to default content
browser.switch_to.default_content()
# Look For Results
web_results = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="apttusps.ApplicationRibbon.{!EntityLogicalName}.Button2.Button-Large"]') 
web_results.click()

# ribbonframe = browser.find_element_by_id('apttus_apts_agreement|NoRelationship|SubGridStandard|Mscrm.SubGrid.apttus_apts_agreement.MainTab.ExportData')

# # browser.find_element_by_class_name('ms-cui-tabContainer ms-cui-tabContainer-lb')
# ribbonframe.click()

# browser.switch_to.frame(ribbonframe)

# Export to Excel
web_results_excel = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="apttus_apts_agreement|NoRelationship|SubGridStandard|Mscrm.SubGrid.apttus_apts_agreement.ExportToExcel-Large"]')
# find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="apttus_apts_agreement|NoRelationship|SubGridStandard|Mscrm.SubGrid.apttus_apts_agreement.ExportToExcel-Large"]')
web_results_excel.click()

time.sleep(15) #seconds
browser.close()
browser.quit()
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error is below:selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="apttus_apts_agreement|NoRelationship|SubGridStandard|Mscrm.SubGrid.apttus_apts_agreement.MainTab.ExportData"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just need a wait in your code for the element:

```
    web_results = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="apttusps.ApplicationRibbon.{!EntityLogicalName}.Button2.Button-Large"]') 
web_results.click()


    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "apttus_apts_agreement|NoRelationship|SubGridStandard|Mscrm.SubGrid.apttus_apts_agreement.MainTab.ExportData"))
)

# ribbonframe = browser.find_element_by_id('apttus_apts_agreement|NoRelationship|SubGridStandard|Mscrm.SubGrid.apttus_apts_agreement.MainTab.ExportData')
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I was able to resolve the error by removing below line so the program just clicks on the static sheet.

Appreciate your help!

Export to Excel
web_results_excel = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="apttus_apts_agreement|NoRelationship|SubGridStandard|Mscrm.SubGrid.apttus_apts_agreement.ExportToExcel-Large"]/a[2]')
web_results_excel.click()

Final Code

```html
# Go back out of iframe to default content
browser.switch_to.default_content()
# Look For Results
time.sleep(5)
web_results = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="apttusps.ApplicationRibbon.{!EntityLogicalName}.Button2.Button-Large"]') 
web_results.click()

time.sleep(5)

# time.sleep(3)
web_results_staticsheet = browser.find_element_by_class_name('ms-cui-ctl-a1Internal')

# browser.find_element_by_class_name('ms-cui-ctl-a2 ') 
web_results_staticsheet.click()


time.sleep(100) #seconds
browser.close()
browser.quit()
```